# Is it possible to manage long-term project for automation testing Win and OSX apps?

Tags: selenium, automation, automated-tests, appium, winappdriver

My current goal is to define a way, how to implement automation testing for Windows and MacOS desktop apps. I would prefer create a Appium-based project (based on my experience) and just handle my project from two OS's. But it seems irrational somehow, so I want to find (if it exists) some kind of tool which allows to write automation tests for both platforms and run them on one machine (currently on MacBook 2021 M1). Is is possible to find something good with all automation-needed features/actions for a long-term project?

Comment: This does not seem irrational at all, you cannot really run Windows app automated tests on macOS. You could create a Windows VM and run the tests inside it but this still is essentially "two OS's". If you at least want to have the same codebase you can look into the [carina](https://github.com/zebrunner/carina) JAVA framework if you want to test the "same" app on different OSs - it will allow you to have different page objects for Windows and for macOS.

Comment: Thanks for the answer, i'll look through it